# Question about Chemistry

Tags: discussion

I have a question (well, multiple questions, it is for a school project) about chemistry, and have committed to the proposal on Area 51.  Only catch is, it is for school, and needs to be asked soon.  Is Physics the correct place to ask a chemistry question before the actual chemistry site reaches beta?

Comment: `the presence or absence of another SE site on a particular topic has no bearing on whether a question on that topic is appropriate here or not.` [From here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21827/addition-of-a-neutral-electrolyte-to-water-how-can-it-increase-conductivity#comment50482_21827)

Comment: @Manishearth Good point, I agree :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Physics.SE is the correct place for *physics* questions.

Now, there is some overlap between chemistry and physics in the study of the electron structure of atoms (and in some specialized places that of molecules) and in the discipline that we call *"thermodynamics and statistical mechanics"* and the chemists call *"physical chemistry"*.

You are welcome to ask the kinds of chemistry question that are *also* physics questions, but please don't ask questions that are *not* physics questions.

There is no guarantee that there is a correct place on the Stack Exchange network for any particular question.

Comment: Okay, I understand now, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

> Is Physics the correct place to ask a chemistry question before the actual chemistry site reaches beta?

**No.**

This is the same thing dmckee said, but just to put it a different way: chemistry questions are not appropriate for Physics Stack Exchange, unless they are also physics questions.

If you think your question might be a physics question, then you can of course go ahead and ask it; just don't be too surprised if it gets closed as off topic. Consider it constructive feedback, not a personal insult - we won't think you're a terrible person or anything like that if you ask a question that gets closed. (If you repeatedly ask questions that get closed, then that's a different story, but just one or two borderline questions isn't a problem.)